# Is there a special name for polynomials related by Möbius tranformation of the variable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, terminology, mobius-transformation

If we take a general polynomial with complex coefficients:

$$C_n z^n+C_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+C_1z+C_0$$

We can apply a general Möbius tranformation to the variable:

$$z=\frac{aw+b}{cw+d},~~~~a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$$

This seems to be the most general transformation which preserves the degree of a polynomial equation (if we discount the degenerate cases, for example assuming $ad-bc=1$), since multiplying by $(cw+d)^n$ we obtain a polynomial in $w$:

$$A_n w^n+A_{n-1}w^{n-1}+\dots+A_1w+A_0$$

The first coefficient, if I'm not mistaken:

$$A_n=C_n a^n+C_{n-1}a^{n-1}c+C_{n-2}a^{n-2}c^2+\dots+C_1ac^{n-1}+C_0c^n$$

> Is there a name for polynomials related by this transformation? Something in the form of "polynomial $P$ is ______ to $Q$ ", or "polynomials $P$ and $Q$ are ______ ".

Comment: I do not see why $A_n$ cannot be zero - in which case the degree will not be preserved.

Comment: Wouldn't such a transformation map a polynomial to a rational function? (It will map to a polynomial if $c=0$, but then it's just a linear transformation.)

Comment: Degree is preserved because when composing maps of the Riemann sphere, the composition of a degree 1 map (the Mobius transformation) and a degree $n$ map (the polynomial, assuming $C_n \ne 0$) must be a degree $n$ map.

Comment: For $a=c=0$ the degree in $w$ will definitely not be $n$ - we do not assume a condition on $a,b,c,d$, like $ad-bc=1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I tried to correct my wording in the third paragrath. I discount degenerate cases. In general, we can say that the transformation and multiplying by $(cw+d)^n$ gives a polynomial in $w$ of degree $ \leq n$. I hope this is enough

Comment: @Semiclassical, see my edit and the above comment please

Comment: @YuriyS I think you really mean any substitution $z\mapsto w=az+b$ for a polynomial $f(z)$, which is sometimes done to be able to apply the Eisenstein criterion. This is, in fact, an *affine transformation*.

Comment: It is not an answer to your question (more than two months later), but, in case it is of interest for you, here is a quite interesting article dealing with such a substitution for matrix polynomials (homepages.wmich.edu/~mackey/mmmm7.pdf).

Comment: @JeanMarie, thank you all the same!